# Error CS1061 says string does not contain definition

Tags: c#

This C# code gives me an error message that the string does not contain definition for AddItem. I tried to add a different identifier, but I don't know which one.

C#:

```cs
const string RIBBON_TAB = "HILLAM TAB";
const string RIBBON_PANEL = "Ribbon button";

public object ToolTip {
    get;
    private set;
}

public BitmapSource Png {
    get;
    private set;
}

// Both OnStartup and OnShutdown must be implemented as public method
public Result OnStartup(UIControlledApplication a) {

    //get the ribbon tab
    try {
        a.CreateRibbonTab(RIBBON_TAB);
    }

    catch(Exception) {} //tab already exists
    // Add a new ribbon panel
    RibbonPanel panel = null;
    List < RibbonPanel > panels = a.GetRibbonPanels(RIBBON_TAB);
    foreach(RibbonPanel pnl in panels) {
        if (pnl.Name == RIBBON_PANEL) {
            panel = pnl;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (panel == null) {
        panel = a.CreateRibbonPanel(RIBBON_TAB, RIBBON_PANEL);
    }

    // Create a push button to trigger a command add it to the ribbon panel.
    string thisAssemblyPath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
    PushButtonData buttonData = new PushButtonData("cmdHelloWorld", "Hello World", thisAssemblyPath, "RevitAddin1.HelloWorld");
    PushButton pushButton = RIBBON_PANEL.AddItem(buttonData) as PushButton;

    // Optionally, other properties may be assigned to the button
    // a) tool-tip
    pushButton.ToolTip = "Say hello world.";
```

I'm expecting to click on panel and it opens a new window with the message: 'Say hello world.'

Comment: Try changing `RIBBON_PANEL.AddItem` to `panel.AddItem`.

Comment: Hi Idle_Mind. Thank you for your suggestion. It help a bit as the error is gone but my Tab Panel went to wrong location on ribbon . I wanted the tool to be under HILLAM_TAB but It went to External Tools tab hmm any idea why?

Comment: I have no idea. I simply analyzed your post and deduced what variable you need to be using based on the code and its comments.  I'm not familiar with what you're doing at all.